# Android: concurrentmodificationexception when filtering a list of objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filter, concurrentmodification

I have an `Arraylist` of objects that starts off being populated from a master list:

```
List<Object> myObjects = new ArrayList<>(masterList);
```

I then run through a set of conditions:

```
for (Condition condition : listOfConditions) {
    applyCondition(condition);
}
```

and begin removing objects:

```
private void applyCondition(Condition condition) {

     if (condition.equals("condition1") {
          for (Object object : myObjects) {
                if (object.doesntMatchCondition1()) {
                      myObjects.remove(object);
                }
          }
     } 

     else if (condition.equals("condition2") { 
     ... etc.
}
```

that should leave me with a final filtered list of objects that match all the conditions.

However, I'm getting a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` the first time that the method tries to remove an object from the myObjects list. Why is this happening? There aren't several threads accessing the list at the same time, and it should be applying the operations synchronously.

This error occurs even if I make the methods `synchronized`.

Comment: Use an Iterator or Streams.

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because you are deleting your object from the collection during an iteration. What is not allowed. You could store the to be delted objects in an additional list and then do something like myObjects.removeAll(newList)

Comment: Thanks. In the end the duplicate question solved my problem (using an iterator to remove items doesn't throw the exception)